# phonegap plugin loadUrl from execute function

Tags: android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am trying to implement an error screen when a certain event is triggered in my js code. Since the error page is local, my attempt to set `window.location.href = 'file:///android_assets/www/error.html'` throws an error indicating cannot load local resource.

So I am trying to create a plugin in android and doing the following:

```
    public PluginResult execute(final String action, final JSONArray data, final String callBackId) {
//      final DroidGap currentCtx = (DroidGap) ctx.getContext();

        final Context currentCtx = cordova.getActivity();
        MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) currentCtx;
        ma.loadUrl("file:///android_assets/www/error.html");

        PluginResult result = null;
        return result;
    }
```

The problem is this code doesn't load the URL. I am not sure if this is the right way of calling. Any insights please?

I see an error like: 
`08-16 01:08:48.974: I/Web Console(730): JSCallback Error: Request failed. at file:///android_asset/www/cordova-2.0.0.js:3698`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works for me when I add a public loadUrl in the MainActivity

```
//MainActivity
public void loadUrl() {
    String url = "http://google.com";
    super.loadUrl(url, 30000);
}
```

....

```
//Plugin
public PluginResult execute(final String action, final JSONArray data, final String callBackId) {

    MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) context;
    ma.loadUrl();

    PluginResult result = null;
    return result;
}
```

I'm using PhoneGap 1.8.1 but I don't think it matter in this case.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by [guya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/275333/guya) worked for me after I updated the "context" using "cordova.getActivity()".

(NOTE: I have only one activity to "get" in this case)

I'm using Cordova 2.1.

```
   public PluginResult execute(String action, JSONArray args, String callbackId) {
        if (action.equals(ACTION_GO_URL)) {
            MainActivity ma = (MainActivity) cordova.getActivity();
            ma.mainLoadUrl();
            return new PluginResult(Status.OK);
        } else {
            return new PluginResult(PluginResult.Status.INVALID_ACTION);
        }
    }
```

Don't forget to add the import of the MainActivity on your plugin.

```
import com.YOUR_NAMESPACE.MainActivity;
```

And add the public method to your MainActivity.

```
public void mainLoadUrl() {
    String url = "http://www.google.com";
    super.loadUrl(url);
}
```